# Display of Nordic charset eg: ø (o/) AIDA 6.0, Dolphin Proff 6.03

Tags: smalltalk, aida

When AIDA sends a textstring to my FireFox or chrome browsers containing danish chars eg. ø(o/) or Æ (AE) they are displayed as �. I have tried:
 (AIDASite named:'PIYHsite')defaultLanguage:'DA'
And controlled site settings in the site, it reads: defaultLanguage='DA' with no succes.

Any hints on what I have overlooked?
Thanks in advance
Soren

Addendum. AIDA uses UTF8 encoding, and after looking in the source, I can see that my settings of defaultLanguage='DA' actually is to select different sourcedokuments for different languages. So it is understandable that it not changes the seen behaviour. Any UTF8 tricks I may have overlooked?

Comment: is everything ok with encoding?

Comment: Thanks - AIDA uses UTF8 as I understand. But it is a large package and exactly where to look in it for this problem I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Problem (nearly solved). AIDA HTMLResponse header had: charset=UTF-8, but AIDA did not convert to UTF. (Conversion commented out due to lack of the class StreamEncoder in the Dolphin image). Solution: In WebPage>>initPageHeaderLinks remove: charset=UTF-8.
I think the browser then defaults to the local char encoding in my Win 7 OS, which AIDA also use. (Nearly solved) Means: I am using a local server while 'Webbifacting' my app. When a foreign client is served the problem may very well showUp again.